# I wanna study on iOS App and Game development but I don't have any Mac device

Tags: xcode, windows

I know little bit C Programming and Java. I want to start hard study on Objective-C and all other stuff that needed for Apple App and Game development, But I don't have any MacBook or iMac where I can learn them with xCode. I have just a iPhone 5.

Can anyone please let me know, how can I process on my Windows/Ubuntu computer?

Thank you,

John

Comment: try visual studio 2015 Community RC and select to install tools for apache cordova during the installation, then create your first multi-platform app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are a newer developer, it will be easier and a more efficient use of your time to learn Apple's new language, Swift. I don't believe the rumors that Apple is planning to phase objective-C out any time soon, but I know from experience that it is much easier to go from Java to Swift than to objective-C, especially considering that objective-C has little benefit over swift in programming for iOS.

You can download the [Swifty](http://Swifty%20-%20Learn%20how%20to%20code%20in%20Swift!%20by%20Johannes%20Berger%20https://appsto.re/us/HPb10.i) app on your phone today for free to start learning swift.

Comment: I saw some tutorial of Swift but they seems I need a Mac computer to program on Swift.

Comment: You need a Mac to program in Xcode but you can still practice on your phone. If you really want to start programming for iOS, you can look into www.macincloud.com, which allows you to rent a virtual Mac on a monthly basis, but that gets expensive. I agree that your best bet would be buying a Mac or finding one you could use.

Comment: You should also look into Silver from Remobjects, which may let you program swift through a plugin to visual studio. Sorry I just remembered this.

Answer (score 0):

Working on PC always have some difficulties, my advise is go and buy a mid price level Mac mini. Probably you can connect your monitory with it.

http://store.apple.com/us/buy-mac/mac-mini

Here is the Video tutorial for your first time :

http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Visual-Studio-Tools-for-Apache-Cordova/Creating-your-first-Hello-World-app-with-Tools-for-Apache-Cordova

Comment: oww no way, I don't have any money atm :( :/ . I just study coz I am only fifteen, I wanna start with my windows computer for now.

Comment: OK Ra John, no worries, everything is possible, then try apache cordova with Visual Studio. Promise me, when you earn your first money (mean few  freelance jobs),  go and buy a Mac mini! Then you'll understand what I mean ;)

Comment: You're welcome Ra John ;)